# Here API Android :change route in navigation

Tags: android, here-api

i m wondering if there is a better way to change route after the navigation started ,  i m doing this :
-Stop navigation
-Remove old route
-Calculate new route
-Start navigation 
i want to be able to add a waypoint after navigation already started and it calcults automaticly the reroute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, new waypoints need a recalculation. And also insertion point is on you or your users, since this can be pretty anything from new startpoint, new endpoint or whatever you like...